# Avoid visual artifacts when initializing background (main) window

Tags: inno-setup

I try to change the default background image by my custom image.

I use this code:

```pascal
procedure PrepareBackGround;
var
   BackgroundBitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
   TopLeftLabel: TLabel;
   BitmapFileName: String;
   sWidth,sHeight : integer;
begin         
   sWidth:=GetSystemMetrics(0);
   sHeight:=GetSystemMetrics(1);
   MainForm.Width := 848;
   MainForm.height := 660; 
   MainForm.top := (sHeight-MainForm.height)/2;
   MainForm.Left := (sWidth-MainForm.Width)/2; 

   BitmapFileName :=ExpandConstant('{src}\SetupFiles\FullScr.bmp');
   BackgroundBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
   BackgroundBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(BitmapFileName);
   BackgroundBitmapImage.Parent :=MainForm;
   BackgroundBitmapImage.Align:=alCLient;
   BackgroundBitmapImage.Stretch:=True;

   TopLeftLabel := TLabel.Create(MainForm);
   TopLeftLabel.Parent := MainForm;
   TopLeftLabel.Left := 10;
   TopLeftLabel.Top := 10 ;
   TopLeftLabel.Font.Color := clBlack;
   TopLeftLabel.color := clWhite;
   TopLeftLabel.Font := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.Font;
   TopLeftLabel.Font.Style :=  [fsitalic,fsBold];
   TopLeftLabel.Caption := 
     'SoftwareXXX ' +
     GetIniString(
       'Version Installation', 'Installation', 'unknown',
       ExpandConstant('{src}\Sources\File.Ver'));
   TopLeftLabel.WordWrap := WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.WordWrap;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard; 
begin
  { to display an image in background Window( see in Supportfunction.iss) }
  PrepareBackGround;
  { ... }
end;
```

But when I run that, I see some lighting (as a flash). The reason of that light is the load of the new image.

How I can avoid this light? How can modify or access to the `MainForm` to modify the background image before it's displayed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i can correct this falsh by :

```
[Setup]
WindowVisible=No
```

and i add at the end in my function

```
procedure PrepareBackGround;
var
   //...
begin         
    //..  
   MainForm.Show;
end;
```

Comment: Not a bad solution. +1. Though just note that the `WindowVisible=no` has side effects. You cannot set `WindowShowCaption=no` or `WindowResizable=no` anymore. And the wizard form will have redundant minimize button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "flash", you refer to, is due to a resize of the maximized main window.

Try using [`WindowStartMaximized` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_windowstartmaximized):

```
[Setup]
WindowStartMaximized=no
```

---

There's no event that is triggered before main window is shown, but after it is created.